# Segue Is Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, storyboard

I am developing one iPad application using storyboard.In my application i have 2 view controllers(First view controller and Modal view controller).In my first view controller i have one table view with cell containing one button.If I click the button in each cell i need to go to modal view controller.I conected the modal view controller and button by using a segue but if i try to run the program the Xcode shows compailation failed due to story board error.How can i set segue for button in table cell for stroyboard.

Comment: please provide your error log

Comment: please provide code of your action button and error log

Answer (score 0):

you connect the segue from "First view controller" to "Modal view controller" and give an Identifier  say "ModelSegue". and you might have a target method for the button tableviewcell, so programmatically push the view controller in your button target method like

- (void)buttonTarget:(id)sender
  {
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ModelSegue" sender:sender];
  }

Comment: i post one mores question some one give some advice but did not get the concept.would you please help me to solve this issue.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989205/how-to-return-rest-kit-response-object